# How to use arrays in mongodb query inside node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, extjs4.2

ExtJs Code:

```
tab.getStore().getProxy().setExtraParam("CCP", filterDetails );
                tab.getStore().load();
```

Node.js Code:

```
exports.loadGrid = function(req, res){
    var filteredDetails = req.param('CCP');
    console.log(filteredDetails );
    mongoClient.connect(config.database.path, function(err, db) {
        if(err) throw err;
        var collection = db.collection('trades');
        // Locate all the entries using find
        if(filteredDetails != null)
        {
            collection.find({$and:[ filteredDetails ]}).toArray(function(err, results) {
                console.log(results);
                res.send(results);
                db.close();
            });
        }
        else
        {
            collection.find().toArray(function(err, results) {
                console.log(results);
                res.send(results);
                db.close();
            });
        }
    })
};
```

Here is my result:

[ '[object Object]', '[object Object]' ]

This is the log printed in the console for the code[console.log(filteredDetails );].
 Here i want values instead of object.

Comment: Try `console.log( JSON.stringify( results ) )` and similarly in your send

Comment: JSON.stringify is part of ECMAScript standard. Thus you don't need to "require" it. And you can also find it in MongoDB shell.

Answer (score 1):

You might also try `util.inspect` to inspect your array of objects.

```
var util = require('util');

console.log(util.inspect(filteredDetails, { showHidden: true, depth: null }));
```

Util is one of node's core modules. You can find more information on it here: http://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options